# VB.NET How to receive two values from serial waiting for the second

Tags: vb.net

So I have the code below that is connected to a pager, the problem I have is sometimes a 'page message' will be split across two actual "pages" but if its split it will always contain (part 1 of 2) or (part 2 of 2), the problem I have is that my sub receives the page data and then calls the sub Parse_Page which is fine for single paged massages.

Ive tried to test with an if statement say if PageData.contains ("(Part 1 of 2)") and that's all good and well but I need store that string somewhere and somehow wait for the part message to arrive before putting part 1 and part 2 together and calling the "Parse_page" sub. I've tried various if's and arrays but I;m getting confused in what has to happen. Any ideas on how to do it?

```
Public Sub serial_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles serial.DataReceived

    Dim PageData As String = serial.ReadLine

    Parse_Page(Nothing, Nothing)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a global var.

```
Dim PageData1 As String = String.Empty
Dim PageData2 As String = String.Empty

Public Sub serial_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles serial.DataReceived

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(PageData1) = True Then
        PageData1 = serial.Readline
    ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(PageData2) = True Then
        PageData2 = serial.Readline
        PageData = PageData1 & PageData2
        PageData1 = String.Empty
        PageData2 = String.Empty
        Parse_Page(Nothing, Nothing)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but this will just test if the current page contains a set string, I can do that and test for "part 1 of 2" for example but how do I capture the first part message and then wait for the second part to arrive then put them both together?

Comment: Just edited my answer. You might need some extra checks in each IF part to check if it really is the needed data. But depends on your incoming data